# Python: How can I make my gtk window move slowly

Tags: python, variables, window, pygtk

I would like my gtk window to move from the middle of the screen to the left side of the screen. Not all at once, but slowly. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from termcolor import *
import os
import pygtk
import gtk
from qjfunctions import *
import time
pygtk.require('2.0')
SaveDir = "/home/marc/QuickJotTexts"

# main starts here    
window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
window.set_size_request(400, 400)
window.move(x,y)
window.set_title("QuickJot")

#####IMAGES#####
settings = gtk.Image()
settings.set_from_file("settings.png")
settings.show()
info = gtk.Image()
info.set_from_file("info.png")
info.show()

#####BUTTONS####
button1 = gtk.Button("Create A New Thought")
button1.connect("clicked", new_file)
button2 = gtk.Button("View A Thought")
button2.connect("clicked", view_file)
button3 = gtk.Button("Delete A Thought")
button3.connect("clicked", delete_file)
button4 = gtk.Button()
button4.add(settings)
button4.connect("clicked", setting_menu)
button5 = gtk.Button()
button5.add(info)
button5.connect("clicked", info_menu)

fixed = gtk.Fixed()
fixed.put(button1, 125, 140)
fixed.put(button2, 148, 175)
fixed.put(button3, 143, 210)
fixed.put(button4, 350, 10)
fixed.put(button5, 305, 10)

window.add(fixed)
window.show_all()

reminder()
gtk.main()
```

Take note to the fact that the line where it says:

```
window.move(x,y)
```

Is the line of code that will make the window move.
A loop will probably be needed for this, something like this:

```
loop = 1
while loop == 1:
x = 100
y = 100
#here is where the x and y values will change, slowly moving the window like an animation
x = x-1
y = y-1
window.move(x,y)
```

I could be totally wrong, and there could be a simpler way to do that that I have over looked. Feedback would be appreciated.
Thanks StackOverflow:)

Answer (score 0):

Use a repeated timeout via `gobject.timeout_add(interval, callback, ...your.data...)` and do the "movement" there. For more details see the [pygtk2 tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TimeoutsIOAndIdleFunctions.html)

---

Also note that pygtk2 is getting old and the new way to do things is to use the introspection bindings via gintrospect.